# Javascript request error, status code 503

Tags: javascript, php, http

I've an issue requesting some data in JS and i get status code 503 and also a message that i don't know what it means,it seems like the memory located to the request is not enought and i would like to know why and how to solve, here the screenshot:

[image]

You can manually see it on chrome's dev tools (network section) on this page: [PAGE](https://smm-mainpanel.com/services)

You can also notice that if you refresh the page more times the requests that fails are everytime different.

I won't write all the code here because is too long, but i leave the link, i'm sorry but this is not my own script and it is compressed.

this is the file that triggers the error.
[CODE](https://smm-mainpanel.com/assets/js/vendors/jquery-3.2.1.min.js)

THIS IS THE ERROR FROM CPANEL:

```
couldn't create child process: /usr/sbin/suphp for /home/smmmainp/public_html/index.php, referer: https://smm-mainpanel.com/services
```

Comment: https://http.cat/503

Comment: yes service unavailable but why? how can i solve?

Comment: Talk to your hosting provider.

Comment: Do you think it is an hosting problem? not a memory overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up your site and your server is returning an **Exceeded Resource Limit Error**  [Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP4iU.png).

*"The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later".*

It is not a JavaScript problem, it is an HTTP Request problem, server-side. The "jQuery" that's showing in your Console is probably the Request Initiator, and when some problem happens with your Request, the jQuery needs to Handle it and send an error message. But stills a Server-Side error.

You need to look into your cPanel, go to "Stats" page and look your HTTP Request Limit, in order to know how much requests daily (or per hour) your server handle. Review your Server Provider Plan and contact them.

Best regards!

Comment: Thank you! So this is the cause? https://imgur.com/a/VjNiXNf this is my cpanel resource usage. but i don't understand if i reached the limit of http requests why if i refresh the page some requests works and some not? shouldn't be all blocked? and how can i solve this?

Comment: The server, like any other machine, has a limit of processes running at the same time.  The servers use a lot of processes to load your pages such as SQL, PHP, Stats, cPanel, Nginx or Apache. Each one is a separate process. E.g.:  PHP processor has a limit of threads to run, and when its over, only the PHP environment stops to run. This is the explanation for some things in your site stills running and another doesn't. You need to buy another plan that brings you more execution times _per day_ or limit how much people can access your site, or find if your code is making unnecessary requests.